# Consider a user model in prisma with two possible roles of an enum, how do I make a model that has a user list for each role?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, relationship, prisma

```
enum Roles {
  ADMIN
  FREQUENTER
}

model Environment {
  id          Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  admins      User[]
  frequenters User[]
}

model User {
  id           Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  name         String
  registration String     @unique
  password     String
  role         Roles
  createdAt    DateTime   @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime   @updatedAt
}
```

this way i receive the error "Error validating model "Environment": Ambiguous relation detected. The fields `admins` and `frequenters` in model `Environment` both refer to `User`. Please provide different relation names for them by adding `@relation()."

Comment: Did you try adding relation names?